# How to chose SAML over Google Password authentication in GCP

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, single-sign-on, saml, google-workspace

I am facing an issue with GCP and unmanaged users.
After using the transfer tool to invite someone in the organization, he unfortunately didn't read the email and the invitation timed out.
For some reasons I was not able to resend the invitation so I instead decided to create a new user.
However he keeps getting the following error now:

[image: gcperror]

I checked the logs and I figured he is not using the same login type as other peoples, SAML is me and Google password being the user having the issue.

[image]

Can anyone help me on how to enforce using SAML on the authentication?
I am using Azure AD as IdP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me so I'll leave it here in case anyone struggle with the same issues.

1. In Azure Portal, select Enterprise Application and look for Google.
   Then select Google Cloud/ G Suite connector

[image: gsuite]

2. In Single sign-on ensure the contoso.com is replaced by your dns and ensure the last part framed in red is accurate to your own requirements.

[image: sso]

3. Finally make sure you've enabled provisioning to have your users actually provisionned from Azure and not created in Google Workspace only.

[image: provisionning]